# use installed lightshot app for taking screenshot instead of default screenshot provided by ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, screenshot

I just installed lightshot for screenshot following guide from it's website

[image]

but when i press print screen buttton "prt sc" it uses default print screen.

How can i use lightshot print screen instead of the default screenshot.

Thank you

Comment: If you're running Gnome, you could take advantage of the [many Gnome extensions}(https://extensions.gnome.org/) available to you, including screenshot tools. It seems to me that installing/running a screenshot tool through Wine is a very heavy (from a resources perspective) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute any screenshot tool of choice by redefining the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key.

- Go to Settings - Keyboard and select "View and customize shortcuts"
- In the "Keyboard shortcuts" dialog, open the "Screenshots" section. When the "Set shortcut" dialog appears, hit <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> to clear the key assignment.
- Return to the "Keyboard Shortcuts" dialog. Open the section "Custom shortcuts".
- Click the "Add Shortcut" button. In the "Add Custom Shortcut" dialog, provide a name, the command to launch your screenshot tool, then assign <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> as the shortcut.